# how to covert base64 string to file object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I have to convert a base64 encoded string to file object in java script so that i can pass that object to php and access that object by FILE variable.

Here is my code:

```
 $(document).delegate(':file', 'change', function () {
     files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
     if (!files.length || !window.FileReader)
     return; // no file selected, or no FileReader support
     filenum = $(this).attr('data');
     $("form#cropmodal #filenum").val(filenum);

     var oMyForm = new FormData();

     for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

     var ext = $("#ImgId" + filenum).val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
     output_format = ext;

     if ($.inArray(ext, ['gif', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg']) == -1) {
     alert('Invalid extension');
     return false;
     }

     var mime_type = "image/jpeg";
    if (typeof output_format !== "undefined" && output_format == "png") {
     mime_type = "image/png";
   }

   var reader = new FileReader();
                                                            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(files[i]);

   reader.onload = function (event) {
   // blob stuff
  var blob = new Blob([event.target.result]); // create blob...
  window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); // and get it's URL

 // helper Image object
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = blobURL;
  //preview.appendChild(image);
   // preview commented out, I am using the canvas instead
  image.onload = function () {
  // have to wait till it's loaded
  var cvs = document.createElement('canvas');
  cvs.width = image.naturalWidth;
  cvs.height = image.naturalHeight;
  var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  var newImageData = cvs.toDataURL(mime_type, 50 / 100);
  var result_image_obj = new Image();
  result_image_obj.src = newImageData;                                                         
  var cvs = document.createElement('canvas');
  cvs.width = result_image_obj.naturalWidth;
  cvs.height = result_image_obj.naturalHeight;
  var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d").drawImage(result_image_obj, 0, 0);

  var type = "image/jpeg";
  var data = cvs.toDataURL(type);
  data = data.replace('data:' + type + ';base64,', '');

  var the_file = new Blob([window.atob(data)], {type: 'image/jpeg',  encoding: 'utf-8'}); 
   oMyForm.append("media[]", the_file);
  oMyForm.append("_token", "{{ csrf_token() }}");

   }
  };
 }
```

});

When i alert "the_file" it will show "Object Blob", but i need "Object File"

Comment: It is unclear what you are actually trying to do here. A few lines of example code would be very useful if you actually want a useful answer rather than a bunch of **guesses**

Comment: i just added the code, please go through it.

Comment: Just got the solution at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata Thanks @Stoive

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use like this:
```

[base64 decode javascript](https://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/qaght/)